# Can't show the icon for a button in Toolbar Items with UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm working on an app for the UWP and Android platforms. I want to set an icon for a button in the navigation toolbar. This is my code in XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="btnAbout" Text="ABOUT" Order="Primary" Clicked="OnNextPageButtonClicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

and this is the code in the associated .cs file:

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing() 
{ 
    base.OnAppearing();
    btnAbout.IconImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("Monk.about.ico"); 
}
```

Everything works just fine on Android, but in UWP, even though I can click the button, I can't see the icon.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi Leonardo. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for posting a question! Would you be able to add screenshots of the Android and UWP apps to further demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I write it for those who need it:

it was necessary to define the path of the icons according to the type of OS destination for compilation.

For Android I had to copy the image to all the "drawable ..." folders and set its compilation property as "AndroidResource".

For UWP I had to copy the png file to the Assets folder and then set its compilation property as "Content".

Finally, you must indicate in the XAML file which paths to use depending on the type of compilation. The code is as follows:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="ABOUT" Clicked="OnNextPageButtonClicked" Priority="0">
            <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="Android">info</On>
                    <On Platform="UWP">Assets/info.png</On>
                </OnPlatform>
            </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        </ToolbarItem> 
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that while UWP can display an `.ico` file in a `Image` element, it does not work with the `BitmapIcon`, which Xamarin.Forms uses underneath for `ToolbarItem`. Therefore you will unfortunately not be able to use this very file on UWP. However, you can convert your icon to a `.png` image and that will display on all platforms without problems.

Comment: I tried to use a .png file instead of a .ico file but it is still displayed only on Android and not on UWP

Answer (score 1):

Do the change of the code below and set the .ico file Properties> Build Action to Content.
[image]

**Change:**

```
btnAbout.IconImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("Monk.about.ico");
```

**To:**

```
btnAbout.IconImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("Monk.about.ico");
```

**Or you could set the IconImageSource in XAML.**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Primary"
                 Text="Icon Item"
                 Priority="0"
                 IconImageSource="Monk.about.ico"
                 Clicked="OnItemClicked" />
```

**My .ico file:**

[image]

**My result:**

[image]

Comment: if I try with your method I don't get any button icon in the toolbar items. Neither in UWP, nor in Android. Even if I convert the .ico file to .png

Comment: Interesting, for some reason the icon I have tried did not show up on pure UWP app when I used `.ico` file. Surprised it does work in Xamarin.Forms :-O